# Error in finding a minimum in nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, minimum

```
list1=[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0]]
runner=min(list1[:][1])
```

This is giving an error like:

> ```
> runner=min(list1[:][1]) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
> ```

How can i find the min value of the floats (second elements)

Comment: What language is this? Consider adding a language tag to your question.

Comment: `list1[:][1]` contains `['Berry', 37.21]`. How can you find the minimum between a float and a string ?

Comment: i want to find the minimum value between all floats (second elements). How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the result you want, you'll need to iterate over this list!

```
min([el[1] for el in list1])
```

What you're actually doing with your statements is selecting element 1 from the list, then trying to find the minimum of `['Berry', 37.21]` which obviously raises `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'` since "Berry" is not a float that min can compare!

Hope that helps!